# Split array into chunks of alternating sizes

Tags: php, arrays, split, chunks

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
)
```

I want to split the array into alternating chunks. (size 2 then 3 then 2 then 3 etc)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 9
        )

)
```

Comment: Your example shows 3 then 2 then 3, 2 3 etc, i.e., it starts with 3 instead of 2 as in your text.

Comment: @dontomaso Either way is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work:

```
$a = array(0 => 0,1 => 1,2 => 2,3 => 3,4 => 4, 5 => 5, 6 => 6,7 => 7,8 => 8,9 => 9);
$chunks = array();
$i=1;
while(count($a)){
    $chunks[] = array_splice($a, 0,(2+($i%2)),array());

    $i++;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($chunks);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Iterated calls of `array_splice()` seems like a great way to go.  Here is a cleaner version of István Őri's answer.  Subtracting from 5 removes the need to use the modulus operator.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YQ5Sp))

```
$array = range(1, 10);

$chunks = [];
$chunkSize = 3;

while ($array) {
    $chunkSize = 5 - $chunkSize;
    $chunks[] = array_splice($array, 0, $chunkSize);
}
var_export($chunks);
```

This snippet modifies `$array` as it iterates.  `array_splice()` keeps removing elements from the front of the array.  Eventually the array will become empty and the `while()` condition will fail -- breaking the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) for splitting the array, but you need to set conditions right? On what basis do you wanna split them?

And you can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to bring them back into an `array` of arrays.

In case of your current code, the code will be:

#### PHP Code

```
<?php
    $array = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    $final = array(
        array_splice($array, 0, 3),
        array_splice($array, 1, 2),
        array_splice($array, 1, 2),
        array_splice($array, 1, 2),
    );
    print_r($final);
?>
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 9
        )

)
```

#### Fiddle here: http://codepad.org/JzxcZ2Q1

Comment: They just need to be split in the same order as the original array, like the example I gave. Can you show an example of how I can do it with these functions?

Comment: Its done. Check out the example and the fiddle giving you the same output. @Jleagle

Comment: Since I don't like editing other people's answers, I made a paste based on yours with some corrections. http://codepad.org/1U4BRAzJ .You need to call array_splice each time with the starting point 0 and length, i.e array_splice(0, 3), array_splice(0, 2).

Comment: Thanks, I was going to accept this and convert it to a looped version for when there is more than 9, but @István beat me to it

Comment: Why is this answer upvoted?  It misses the 4th element entirely.  It does not create the desired output structure.  The code isn't even dynamic.  There aren't any redeeming qualities in this answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa Please explain, I am still not sure, but do you still understand it's an answer from last decade?   I am now very much mature with my answers and the style of writing in the past ten years. I hope you agree and accept the fact.   The reason I say this is, now both the accepted answer and my answer are outdated and there are much much better methods to do the same in PHP 7 or PHP 8 in a simple way.

Comment: Please [edit] this answer to make it correct.  If this answer doesn't represent your current level of knowledge and care, please bring it up to your current level.  An answer's age is irrelevant to researchers that are looking to Stack Overflow for knowledge.

Comment: @mickmackusa Happy to do that and thanks for the heads up. Will update it in a while. 

Comment: @mickmackusa I hope you do understand that I (and others) have been in Stack Overflow for a long time and personally I have answered more than 5500 times and it's definitely impossible for me to keep checking all the answers to be correct and updated? But yes, I'll happily update this answer, and you know what? Any time you can refer to this answer and create a new question.   In that way, you can preserve the historic importance of this answer. Agree?

Comment: I hammer php questions all day long.  I prefer to direct researchers to page that consist of correct, explained, and high-quality advice.  In this way, I rely on others to maintain their own content.  This is why I blow my whistle often.  This is in no way an attack on you, but your post is not great content.  I am delighted that you have agreed to edit it in the near future.  Thanks.  (I also have thousands of posts and it is very hard to maintain them all -- I like it when I am notified of a suboptimal answer because I only want to show researchers good coding practices.)

Comment: @mickmackusa Awesome, thanks for your efforts too! But I am still curious why decade old answers.   Nice to meet you boss! 

Comment: I never discriminate pages based on age when I curate content for Stack Overflow. I cannot answer new questions because they are all duplicates.  I have been combing Stack Overflow for days while cleaning up the insane number of redundant [tag:transpose] questions.  This is not a transposing question but I found it while searching.  Stack Overflow has too much knowledge scattered in too many places and researchers are likely to miss a real gem.  I think we, high-reppers, need to focus on cleaning up SO so that this place becomes the "Researchers' Paradise" that it was designed to be.

Comment: @mickmackusa Wow, nice to know... Yea, this happens and it's very usual in Stack Overflow as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this, it isn't the most elegant, but it will just do the trick for you - and you can modify it nicely and adapt it to suit your purposes further:

```
<?php

$originalArray = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);


$counter=count($originalArray);
$isTwo=true;
$newArray=array();
$arrElement=0;
$i=0;
while($i<$counter)
{
    if($isTwo)
    {
        $newArray[$arrElement]= array();
        for($j=0; $j<2; $j++)
        {
            $newArray[$arrElement][$j]=$originalArray[$i+$j];
        }
        $i+=2;
        $isTwo=false;
        $arrElement++;
    }
    else
    {
        $newArray[$arrElement]= array();
        for($j=0; $j<3; $j++)
        {
            $newArray[$arrElement][$j]=$originalArray[$i+$j];
        }
        $i+=3;
        $isTwo=true;
        $arrElement++;
    }
}
    var_dump($newArray);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(3)
    [2]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
    [1]=>
    int(6)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(7)
    [1]=>
    int(8)
    [2]=>
    int(9)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tobechunked_arr = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$chunk_size_arr = array(3,2,3,2);
$j = 0;
foreach($chunk_size_arr as $key => $val)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < $val; $i++)
    {
        $result_arr[$key][] = $tobechunked_arr[$j];
        $j++;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result_arr);
```

Comment: This code-only answer is not flexible.  It requires the developer to know exactly how many  elements are in `$tobechunked_arr`; otherwise it risks breaking.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<?php
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2, true));
?>
```

**Update**

```
<?php 
$myArray = array("abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stu","vwx","yz");
$newArray = array_chunk($myArray, 2, false);
// Now process the multidimensional array made from array_chunk()
$i = 0;
foreach ($newArray as $inner_array) {
    $i++;
    echo "<h2>Chunk $i</h2>";
    while (list($key, $value) = each($inner_array)) {    
        echo "$key: $value <br />"; 
    }
}
?>
```

**Output**

**Chunk 1**

0: abc

1: def

**Chunk 2**

0: ghi

1: jkl

**Chunk 3**

0: mno

1: pqr

**Chunk 4**

0: stu

1: vwx

**Chunk 5**

0: yz

Comment: I need it to be in chunks of 2 AND 3

Comment: This only splits it into chunks of 2

Comment: try this $myArray = array("abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stu","vwx","yz");
$newArray = array_chunk($myArray, 2, false);
// Now process the multidimensional array made from array_chunk()
$i = 0;
foreach ($newArray as $inner_array) {
    
    
    if($i==2 || $i==3)
    {
     echo "<h2>Chunk $i</h2>";
     while (list($key, $value) = each($inner_array)) {    
         echo "$key: $value <br />"; 
     }
    }
    $i++;
}