# Create rows of elements based on an array of length values

Tags: php, arrays, split

Is there a neat way to split an array into chunks based on an array of lengths?

Input:

```
$start = range(0, 30);
$length = [3, 7, 2, 12, 6];
```

Desired Output:

```
[
    [0, 1, 2],  // 3
    [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],  // 7
    [11, 12],  // 2
    [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],  // 12
    [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],  // 6
];
```

Comment: Very closely related, slightly earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12195728/2943403

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [**`array_splice`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
$target = array(); // or use []  in PHP 5.4
foreach($length as $i) {
    $target[] = array_splice($start, 0, $i);
}
```

[**Try it.**](http://ideone.com/DLLQcG)

Be advised, this changes `$start`!

Answer (score 2):

This is very easily accomplished with the following:

#### Code:

```
$target = array();
$offset = 0;

foreach ($length as $lengthValue) {
    $target[] = array_slice($start, $offset, $lengthValue);
    $offset += $lengthValue;
}
var_dump($target);
```

#### Explanation:

What you are doing here is using the `array_slice()` method (very similar to the `substr`) to extract the portion of the array and then inserting it into the target array. Incrementing the offset each time allows the function to remember which one to use next time.