# How can I use array_chunk and define the size of each chunk?

Tags: php

I am counting the number of results in each array first and then print them like this:

```
if ($array_count == '12'){

    $output = '<div class="row">';
    $cat_array = array_chunk((array)$cat_array, 3);
    foreach($cat_array as $column) {
        $output .= '<div class="col-xs-3">';
        foreach ($column as $row) {
           $output .= '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><small><a href="' . 
                      $row['subcat_link'] . '" class="cat_filter_link">' . $row['name'] . '</a></small></div></div>';
        }
        $output .= '</div>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';

    }
```

In that case, I am putting `3` into each chunk. Is there any easy way to define, if possible, that I want 4 chunks of 5,3,2,2?

Comment: if array as 5 elements if use 3 ,means 3 value as one array and 2 values as one array

Comment: Take a look at the manuals [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: I checked the manuals but as far as I'm aware you can only give 1 number to define the size of each chunk? So an array of 12 with a defined size of 3 would be 3,3,3,3 while an array of 10 would result in 3,3,3,1. I am trying to define the size of each chunk myself.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Split array into chunks of alternating sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12195728/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) as

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
$result[0] = array_slice($arr, 0,5);
$result[1] = array_slice($arr, 5,3);
$result[2] = array_slice($arr, 8,2);
$result[3] = array_slice($arr, 10,2);
```